# Blank output window in dev c++

Tags: c

Why is there blank output window?

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
    int x, y, sum, product;
    scanf("%d", &x);
    scanf("%d", &y);
    sum = x + y;
    product = x * y;
    printf("%d\n", sum);
    printf("%d\n", product);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. A few things: First of all, a screenshot of the code is not helpful, if you want to show us, rather paste it as code in your question. Secondly, regarding the question, it's much more important how you run the program

Comment: Have you tried typing the numbers that it's trying to read? Try typing something like `4 5` and then press Enter.

Answer (score 0):

I understand your problem what actually happens is that you enter 2 numbers and the result doesn't get displayed right?

So what actually happens is that your result does get displayed but for a split second (remember the output window will close as soon as it finishes executing the code)

You could try this

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
main()
{
 int x,y,sum,product;
 scanf("%d",&x);
 scanf("%d",&y);
 sum=x+y;
 product=x*y;
 printf("%d\n",sum);
 printf("%d\n",product);   
 getch();
}
```

see we are using `getch();` what this function do is actually waits for a user to enter a key so the program hasn't ended unless you press a key, hence you are able to see your output.